# Order numbers from smallest to largest in a column (R)

Tags: r

I would like to order numbers in column **Rn** from the smallest to the highest in my data frame.

**df**

```
    Rn   A                B
999 999 -0.0041211884   1.525399e-02
998 998 -0.0029667159   -1.210880e-02
997 997 -0.0021222138   -8.990619e-04
996 996 -0.0034225292   6.550007e-03
995 995 -0.0022323718   4.861625e-03
734 734 -0.0031919646   0.0183762923
733 733 -0.0041087604   0.0142102064
732 732 -0.0026854019   0.0133951684
731 731 -0.0041045443   -0.0357000188
730 730 -0.0019459701   0.0046243762
73  73  -0.0006597477   -0.00419513
729 729 -0.0041603061   0.0249331809
728 728 -0.0028535264   0.0096861556
```

this doesn't work

```
df1 <- df[order(df$Rn),]
```

It gives this weird output where beginning looks fine but in lower rows you get much smaller values.

```
 1  1   0.0001128847    -0.0175509661
2   10  -0.0040341430   0.0228551849
3   100 -0.0036553401   0.0170472191
4   1000    -0.0039037856   0.0217404106
5   1001    -0.0044555778   0.0251330163
6   1002    -0.0037489438   0.0222520941
7   1003    -0.0042961918   0.0227658211
8   1004    -0.0042094921   -0.0049233698
9   1005    -0.0033948795   0.0188741941
10  1006    -0.0047154595   0.0132463085
11  1007    -0.0034839550   0.0170066750
12  1008    -0.0051087864   -0.0043333614
13  1009    -0.0031065428   0.0164741372
14  101 -0.0029574478   0.0006646753
```

Comment: It is possible that the 'Rn' column is `factor` or `character` class.  Can you do `df[order(as.numeric(as.character(df$Rn))),]`

Comment: Can you check my updated code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `order`

```
df1 <- df[order(as.numeric(as.character(df$Rn))),]
```

If the values to be ordered are limited to a single column

```
df$Rn <- sort(df$Rn)
```

---

Or with `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(as.numeric(as.character(Rn)))
#  Rn             A             B
#72   72 -0.0044245791 -0.0168038397
#73   73 -0.0006597477 -0.0041951300
#720 720 -0.0040865789  0.0126819770
#721 721 -0.0025343630  0.0154996377
#722 722 -0.0045191481  0.0222403429
#723 723 -0.0037375573  0.0208354495
#724 724 -0.0016881401 -0.0010435999
#725 725 -0.0011054237 -0.0350180254
#726 726 -0.0017715684 -0.0332047624
#727 727 -0.0028488675  0.0121699256
#728 728 -0.0028535264  0.0096861556
#729 729 -0.0041603061  0.0249331809
#730 730 -0.0019459701  0.0046243762
#731 731 -0.0041045443 -0.0357000188
#732 732 -0.0026854019  0.0133951684
#733 733 -0.0041087604  0.0142102064
#734 734 -0.0031919646  0.0183762923
#995 995 -0.0022323718  0.0048616250
#996 996 -0.0034225292  0.0065500070
#997 997 -0.0021222138 -0.0008990619
#998 998 -0.0029667159 -0.0121088000
#999 999 -0.0041211884  0.0152539900
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Rn = c(999L, 998L, 997L, 996L, 995L, 734L, 733L, 
732L, 731L, 730L, 73L, 729L, 728L, 727L, 726L, 725L, 724L, 723L, 
722L, 721L, 720L, 72L), A = c(-0.0041211884, -0.0029667159, -0.0021222138, 
-0.0034225292, -0.0022323718, -0.0031919646, -0.0041087604, -0.0026854019, 
-0.0041045443, -0.0019459701, -0.0006597477, -0.0041603061, -0.0028535264, 
-0.0028488675, -0.0017715684, -0.0011054237, -0.0016881401, -0.0037375573, 
-0.0045191481, -0.002534363, -0.0040865789, -0.0044245791), B = c(0.01525399, 
-0.0121088, -0.0008990619, 0.006550007, 0.004861625, 0.0183762923, 
0.0142102064, 0.0133951684, -0.0357000188, 0.0046243762, -0.00419513, 
0.0249331809, 0.0096861556, 0.0121699256, -0.0332047624, -0.0350180254, 
-0.0010435999, 0.0208354495, 0.0222403429, 0.0154996377, 0.012681977, 
-0.0168038397)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("999", "998", 
"997", "996", "995", "734", "733", "732", "731", "730", "73", 
"729", "728", "727", "726", "725", "724", "723", "722", "721", 
"720", "72"))
```

Comment: @giegie can you please update the post with your expected output

Comment: @giegie from the comments, it is not clear.  Can you pleaes update your post with the expected output